# Printing results from line on .txt file depending on the row the user calls

Tags: python

I am working on a program that opens a .txt file and then prompts the user to view an individual student. The file looks like so

```
Bronson 90 85 75 76 
Conor 90 90 90 90
Austyn 50 55 32 75
Mark 96 95 85 85
Anthony 85 85 85 85
```

The program first prints out the name of each student (first word of each column)

```
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    names=[]
    for line in f:
        names.append(line.split()[0])
    print('\nNames of students:')
    print(*sorted(names),sep=' ')
```

then asks which student you want to view:

```
    name = input('Enter name of student whos marks you want to view: '
```

I am trying to write a fragment of code that will print out the contents of whichever name the user types. For example, if the user types 'Conor' the program prints out 90 90 90 90.

I tried to use an if statement but I cannot seem to get it to work. Is someone able to point me in the right direction. This is what I currently have:

```
for line in f:
    if names.append(line.split()[0]) == name:
         print(line)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement would work, but you shouldn't modify the list while looping over it (don't append)

Realistically, you'd use a dictionary keyed by name

```
names=dict() 
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        names[parts[0]] = parts[1:]

name = input("enter a name") 
print(names[name])
```

If you don't need to store each line, then that would look like

```
name = input("enter a name") 
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[0] == name:
            print(parts[1:])
```

Comment: This is sort of what I'm looking for. But I don't want it to print out the square brackets. Eventually i want to be able to access these values to display the avg, max, min etc.

Comment: `print(' '.join(parts[1:]))`